# how to access json data (nested array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON returned by an API.

```
{
    "latitude":45.452176,
    "longitude":9.2741193,
    "timezone":"Europe/Rome",
    "daily":{
        "data":[{
            "time":1580684400,
            "summary":"Clear throughout the day.",
            "icon":"partly-cloudy-day",
            "sunriseTime":1580712180,
            "sunsetTime":1580747580,
            "moonPhase":0.31,
            "precipIntensity":0.0001,
            "precipIntensityMax":0.0005,
            "precipIntensityMaxTime":1580767200,
            "precipProbability":0.09,
            "precipType":"rain",
            "temperatureHigh":61.98,
            "temperatureHighTime":1580739180
        }]
    },
    "offset":1
}
```

I use this code to access the latitude:

```
pippo = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(pippo.latitude);
```

but I am not able to get for example the time property. How to get that data?

Comment: debug to see how *data* looks like

Comment: When you parse `data`, that full object, or the `data` field of the full object?

Comment: `pippo.daily.data[0].time`

Comment: You'd do `pippo.daily.data[0].time` if that's what you're asking

Comment: got it, thanks @RoryMcCrossan. I was doing pippo.daily[0].time and wa not able to get the value. It works fine

Comment: `daily` is an object, so its properties can be access with a `dot notation`, whereas `data` is an array, so you'd access things by their `index`es, for example `data[0]` or `data[1]`.